# Is it possible to build a "Quantum Karnaugh Map"?

Tags: quantum-state, experimental-realization, qubit-mapping

Is it possible to build something similar to the [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) but instead of classical bits input and output with qubits input and output?

Comment: Seems like this could be relevant: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-72469-7

Comment: Note that a quantum computer can peform any classical algorithm as Toffoli gate can be employed as classical NAND gate. Hence classical Karnaugh map is still relevant for quantum computers. However, performing classical algorithm on QC does not bring about any advantage in terms of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has been even patented ...

(19) United States
(12) Patent Application Publication (10) Pub. No.: US 2011/0138344 A1
AHN (43) Pub. Date: Jun. 9, 2011
(54) QUANTUM KARNAUGH MAP

https://patents.google.com/patent/US20110138344A1/en?oq=+US+2011%2f0138344